# EF Code first automatic migration totally messed up

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I'm not sure what I've done, but I get this error when publishing to azure:

```
Automatic migration was not applied because it would result in data loss.
```

Now this is very distubing. My models match my database 100% - so is there a chance there might be data loss if I force it? I'm really confused what to do now.

So much for auto migrations :S Not much automation :) 
I think my error was that I created new models, published it and EF created new tables for them. I then remembered that I forgot do add the models to my `DbContext`. So I added the new `DbSets` to context and published. That's probably where it went wrong. But then again, I didn't know that EF added models to the database if they aren't POCO classes or what ever they are called. Might have been some foreign keys that triggered.. dunno. Anyways I went undo frenzy on my code and deleted all the newly created tables and stuff to get me to my starting point. I thought that might solve it. But noooee stupid me.

Any ideas where to start on this issue? Im gonna jump off a cliff I lose my data :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have EF create the SQL for you, so you can implement the migration manually.  In the package manager console enter:

```
update-database -v -f -script
```

It will open a new window with the SQL that you can look over, and then apply yourself directly to the database.  The last line that enters an entry into the migration history will allow the DbContext to know it's looking at the correct version.

Comment: Actually I have to delete everything except the last line `INSERT INTO [__MigrationHistory]`. But then it says "Invalid object name '__MigrationHistory'." ???

Comment: a few lines above that will be the create table script for __MigrationHistory table, use that to create the history table in your systables.

Comment: Nope, just alot of alter and drop lines. Shall I post the script?

Comment: If you're sure the tables are the same - all you need to do is insert the migration history row.. have you looked through the SQL To ensure that you really will lose the data? Alot of times its warnings about possible data loss, but there isnt any.  Consider changing from nvarchar(max) to nvarchar(100) - if none of your entities have more than 100 characters you wont lose any data.  However, it will give this error because there's a *chance* for data loss

Comment: I see. Not now that I look there most likely no data loss. Its just drops and alters alot of tables. But I've already altered and dropped the tables manually. But I guess it will go into error if I force it, seeing that the tables doesn't excist. I'll add the row in migration history as you said.

Comment: It wont let me insert the binary data manually. What do I do. Can you maybe provide some SQL that will insert the row?

Comment: Or do I just run the script?

Comment: What I normally do when I run into this, is run the script, one line at a time until i find the problems.  It's going to throw errors on the lines that you've already done so skip those.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25248/discussion-between-kasper-skov-and-mark-oreta)

Answer (score 1):

First make a backup! Especially easy if you're using SQL Compact - just copy the file.
Or with LocalDB or SQL Server, Detach, copy file, Attach..

But to give a little more help, generating that script might still have you look for what might cause data loss. I find that adding a new column to become primary key in a table might loose data even if the original column is kept, because of a NOT NULL constraint being enforced on the new column causing (all) rows to be dropped.